# mvc controllers (suitable approach)?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Even after studying from many resources on the internet, my concepts of controllers are still weak.

Currently i am making a simple website with `Laravel` framework with an `admin` integration and `home page`.

Posts are being rendered on the `home pag`e and in `admin panel` too.

Admin can create more `admins` and `posts`.

I have 2 models (`users`, `post`) and 2 controllers `HomeController` and `AdminController`.

Now where should the `Create Post` function go?

I mean should i create 3rd controller (`PostController`) for `showall`, `showsingle`, `create`, `update` and `delete` Posts?

My `AdminController` is already messed up with functions of creating, updating and deleting admins. What should i do and why?

Comment: The best variant is to make 3rd controller (PostController) where you will handle with the posts.

Comment: PostController would be your best bet from what I can understand of your question

Comment: This question is perhaps a bit broad/opinionated for StackOverflow. Personally I'd say it makes sense to have a `PostController` for handing your `post` model; and similarly, use a `UserController` for dealing with your users (*i.e.* creating your admin users).